# Task scheduler with triggers for OS events/monitoring for Windows?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

Is there a free or relatively cheap task scheduler system that can react to things like screen resolution changes, file modifications. etc, and spawn tasks executing my own programs?

For instance, if I want to unzip a file when it appears in a directory?

It seems the built-in task scheduler in Windows only comes as close as spawning the program on a time-based schedule.

What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any pre-built programs.  Seeing as you are a developer, you can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) in the .NET framework.  I've used it to monitor drop boxes in the past.  Any time a file-added event fires you can then invoke whatever program you desire via the command line.

As far as resolution changes, I recommend you checkout the win32 API.  Seeing as windows is not open source, that's your only bet there.  If the event can be hooked into you can create a service to listen for it and run when it fires.

Otherwise, you can create a program where users can change the resolution through your program.  This is possible with C# and platform invoke.  That way you handle the resolution changed event and do whatever else you desire on top.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Task Scheduler to run a batch script every x minutes, which checks for changes to files and uses the [**WMIC**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) utility to check screen resolution changes.  The current states can be saved to a text file which the script checks against.

[**AutoIt v3**](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and [**AutoHotKey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) are other avenues which you could explore, which are certainly powerful enough to do what you want to do, but they would require learning new languages.  AutoHotKey is probably a bit easier, while AutoIt v3 is more powerful.  AutoHotKey is based on the earlier AutoIt v2 syntax.